# Zabbix collecting prometheus encoded data from GitLab runner

Tags: gitlab, prometheus, zabbix, gitlab-runner

I am trying to collect performance data from GitLab runner prometheus Interface to zabbix server.

What do I have:

- A template with a couple of items in zabbix
- a userparameter conf which relies in a
- shell script which fetch data from api call and return it to the user parameter zabbix interface

What I am currently struggling with is:

- because we are using multiple runner, most of the KPI are separated by runner id. Therefore I would like to have a prototype function in my template and script which collects all runner ids, generate items for each runner in zabbix.

But I am really struggling with the prototyping concept in zabbix.

Does anyone would be so kind as to show me an example how to do this?

Comment: first you need to create a Zabbix LLD, using the `api/v4/runners` endpoint in order to retrieve the list of runners, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html (also you can use the zabbix HTTP client instead of the shell script)